# Pass array with ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to add a class to some elements based on the time without page reload

I am creating this array when the page loads. I have a start time, an end time and an identifier.

```
$hrs = array(
    array("2013-07-27 21:00", "2013-07-27 22:00", "one"),
    array("2013-07-27 22:00", "2013-07-27 23:00", "two"),
    array("2013-07-27 23:00", "2013-07-28 00:00", "three"),
);
```

Then I get the current time and grab the identifier from the array. I tried running this script in a separate file time.php using `setInterval` but I can't pass `$hrs`.

```
<ul>
      <li class="one">1</li>
      <li class="two">2</li>
      <li class="three">3</li>


</ul>

var className = "<?php echo $class_name"; ?>
$(className).addClass("red");
```

what is the proper way of running this so I won't need to refresh the page? I did something like this but it alerts error:

* Working code below ******

```
<script>

var hrs = '<?php echo json_encode($hrs); ?>';

//get active class from time.php
  $.ajax({
    url : 'http://domain.com/time.php',
    type : 'POST',
data : { val : hrs },
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (result) {
       className = result['current_class'];

    },
    error : function () {
       alert("error");
    }
})

</script>
```

time.php

```
        $hrs = json_decode($_POST['val']);

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');
    $date  = date('Y/m/d H:i');

    $test = strtotime($date);

    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i", $test);

    $class_name = "";
    foreach ($_POST['val'] as $h) {
    if ($h[0] <= $now and $now <= $h[1]) {
        $class_name = $h[2];fa
        break;
    }
    } 

$class = array(
        'current_class' => ( $class_name ),
    );
    echo json_encode($class);
```

Comment: Neither language understands each other array types. Convert your text to JSON format. PHP send: json_encode( array );. PHP receive: json_decode( str ); JavaScript send: JSON_stringify( array ); and JavaScript recieve: JSON_parse( str );.

Comment: Also the time.php should be on same domain as the ajax call.. otherwise use JSONP.

Comment: It's on the same domain.

Comment: @jeff thanks for the help. I added the code I have now. I was able to send $hrs but I don't know how to send it back. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
var hrs = '<?php echo $hrs; ?>';
```

To:

```
var hrs = '<?php echo json_encode($hrs) ?>';
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are sending data using `POST`

```
type : 'POST',
```

You have to access it using `$_POST`, you are using `$_GET`.

```
$_POST['val']
```

Comment: for newbies using $_REQUEST is also an option.

Comment: @vortex `$_REQUEST` is never an option, it's best to just never even mention it

Comment: @DaveRandom given the case I think it's the best time to mention it as $_REQUEST is not updated when $_POST is updated. as for the "never an option", I can understand why it doesn't have a place in your business logic, that doesn't have to mean it's not useful.

Comment: @vortex Request argument abstractions like `$_REQUEST` are generally a good thing - it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have `$_GET` and `$_POST` contain parameters with the same name and different values/meanings. The reason `$_REQUEST` is a bad thing is because (by default) it also includes data from `$_COOKIE` - this is *not* a good idea, because you are mixing persistent data with transient data and treating them equally. Also to say that one is not updated when the other is suggests that you are modifying these superglobal collections, which is a big no-no.

Comment: I'm not talking about what I'm doing here so please direct these best practices as a comment to the original question

Answer (score 1):

Neither language has any clue about the internals of the other language, your best bet to pass a full array is to encode the AJAX side array to JSON, pass that to your PHP script, and then use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode it into a PHP array.

You could also try passing the parameters with square brackets on the end, with the same name as php interprets this as an array. i.e.

```
file.php?p[]=1&p[]=2&p[]=3&p[]=4&p[]=5
```

Would result in `$_GET['p']` being a 5 item array containing 1 - 5.

The same is also true of post, if you post multiple `p[]`'s, you will end up with `$_POST['p']` as an array of all your elements.